# Getting value between <a > </a> tag by href

Tags: javascript, html

I got a list with all kinds of links. And I want the value between those tags, with this href.

```
<a href="index.php?p=trading?m=21&b=btc">15</a>
```

I want the value 15.

Comment: Yes, it is "possible with PHP, JS or jQuery". So pick the *actual* environment that *you* are using; the answer for each will be different.

Comment: Please note that tags are not keywords.  Stuffing the tag list full of the same words that are in your question (tags, href, between, value) will not help categorize it.  Instead, use tags like `html` or `javascript` to help people find your question.  *Always* be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Comment: Sorry Charles, I will keep that in mind. So you are the reason I got 2 negative vote's for my question? =P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JQuery:

```
$("a").text();
```

You might want to alter the selector if there's more than one link on the page

For example if your link had an id of bitlink you could do

```
var value = $("a#bitlink").text();
```

To select by href:

```
var value = $("a[href='index.php?p=trading?m=21&b=bt']").text()
```

But I'm not sure this is a great idea apart from in exceptional circumstances

Comment: Thanks for answering my question on the first place. But the href tag has no any id or class, only a href. I'm using cURL. I wan't to use the href, to get the value between the <a> tag.

Comment: If you know the href and it won't change you can create a selector using the href $("a[href='href value here']").text();

Comment: Thanks man, I am still a newbie on jQuery. This was exactly what I was looking for. Thought it was only possible with PHP.

Comment: Another question what I've been searching for atleast 3 hours lol.. How can I give the variable 'value' to PHP?

Answer (score 3):

Let that element be stored in `a`. For example, you can get it with

```
var a = document.querySelector('a[href="index.php?p=trading?m=21&b=btc"]')
```

Then, you can use

```
a.innerHTML
```

if you want to get the HTML code inside the element, or

```
a.textContent
```

if you want to get the text inside the element.

Answer (score 2):

PIX06 has provided a great answer, but I will like to bring your attention to 2 other functions of jQuery which you may find useful for your work : .children() and .next()

.next() : http://api.jquery.com/next/

.children() : https://api.jquery.com/children/

.next() Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector. ( which in your case could be "a")

.children() : Get the children of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

Im suggesting these because it is very likely that the < a > < / a > container in which you will like to get your value from, is embedded within or beside another container which would have an identifier that could be selected for and be used for your purpose (class, id, name..).

Therefore, for instance :

```
    ## example for children ##
    ## HTML ##
    <span class="example">
      <a href="index.php?p=trading?m=21&b=btc">15</a>
    </span> 
    ## JQuery ##
    $('.example').children('a').text();

    ## example for next ##
    ## HTML ##
    <span class="example"> some content here </span>
    <a href="index.php?p=trading?m=21&b=btc">15</a>

    ## JQuery ##
    $('.example').next('a').text();
```

Hence, using .next() or .children() might be a more robust way to get to any tag that you are looking for. I hope you find this useful.There are also tree traversal methods that you can check out on jQuery

Cheers

Comment: Very helpfull, I will look further on this because it can be very useful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Or, you could use this:

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName("a")
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
  if( a[i].href == "index.php?p=trading?m=21&b=btc" )
    alert( a[i].innerHTML );
```